# Podman: cannot load TOML value of type map

Tags: podman, toml

I need to fetch this [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/manjarolinux/base) for podman but there is a problem on *registry.conf*

podman gives error

```
podman run --name myfirstcontainer -it  -v /home/jhon:/data:Z manjarolinux/base
Error: error loading registries configuration "/etc/containers/registries.conf": toml: cannot load TOML value of type map[string]interface {} into a Go slice
```

my registry adjust

```
# [[registry.mirror]]
# location = "example-mirror-0.local/mirror-for-foo"
# [[registry.mirror]]
# location = "example-mirror-1.local/mirrors/foo"
# insecure = true
# # Given the above, a pull of example.com/foo/image:latest will try:
# # 1. example-mirror-0.local/mirror-for-foo/image:latest
# # 2. example-mirror-1.local/mirrors/foo/image:latest
# # 3. internal-registry-for-example.net/bar/image:latest
# # in order, and use the first one that exists.
#
[[registry.mirror]]
prefix ="docker.io"
location = "https://hub.docker.com/r/manjarolinux/base"
insecure =true
```

what is wrong

Comment: Found this issue on Github: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/5764 . Looks like a 'registry' block is required in addition the 'registry.mirror' block.

Comment: thanks this issue topic helped too much, solved my problem.`unqualified-search-registries`,  `[[registry]]` and [[registry.mirror]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to define is an array, `mirror`, belonging to the top-level key `registry`, but it's unclear whether `registry` holds a single object or an array of objects.

To use `registry` as a single object,

```
[registry]
[[registry.mirror]]
prefix = "docker.io"
location = "https://hub.docker.com/r/manjarolinux/base"
insecure = true
```

This corresponds to the YAML document

```yaml
registry:
  mirror:
    - prefix: docker.io
      location: https://hub.docker.com/r/manjarolinux/base
      insecure: true
```

or the JSON document

```json
{
  "registry": {
    "mirror": [
      {
        "prefix": "docker.io",
        "location": "https://hub.docker.com/r/manjarolinux/base",
        "insecure": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If the `registry` is supposed to be an *array* (which seems more likely), then use `[[registry]]` in place of `[registry]`, which would add a `-` in front of `mirror` in the YAML equivalent document, and a `[...]` array structure around the object containing `mirror` in the JSON equivalent.